# SqlDataAdapter problems

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have two tables.

*Customers* (int id, nvachar name (250), int age)

*Bonus* (int id, int customer_id References Customers (id), int someAmount)

I need to add, delete, update information about Customers and Bonus.

When I add a new customer, programm automacilly create a new entry about this customer in table Bonus.
When I delete customer, programm delete entry about this customer in in table Bonus.

There is a problem to save it to sql database.

I have these SQL-commands:

```
//Bonus
SqlCommand inscmdT = new SqlCommand();
inscmdT.CommandText = "Insert into Bonus (customer_id, someAmount) values(@customer_id, @someAmount); select id = @@IDENTITY from Bonus";
inscmdT.Connection = conn;
inscmdT.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "customer_id");
inscmdT.Parameters.Add("@someAmount", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "someAmount");

SqlCommand updcmdT = new SqlCommand();
updcmdT.CommandText = "UPDATE Bonus SET customer_id = @customer_id, someAmount = @someAmount WHERE id = @id";
updcmdT.Connection = conn;
updcmdT.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "customer_id");
updcmdT.Parameters.Add("@someAmount", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "someAmount");
updcmdT.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "id");

SqlCommand delcmdT = new SqlCommand();
delcmdT.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Bonus WHERE id = @id";
delcmdT.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "id");
delcmdT.Connection = conn;


//Customers

SqlCommand inscmdS = new SqlCommand();
inscmdS.CommandText = "Insert into Customers (SessionTime, movie, hall, age) values(@SessionTime, @age); select id = @@IDENTITY from Customers";
inscmdS.Connection = conn;
inscmdS.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250, "SessionTime");
inscmdS.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "age");

SqlCommand updcmdS = new SqlCommand();
updcmdS.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET SessionTime = @SessionTime, age = @age WHERE id = @id ";
updcmdS.Connection = conn;
updcmdS.Parameters.Add("@SessionTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250, "SessionTime");
updcmdS.Parameters.Add("@age", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "age");
updcmdS.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "id");

SqlCommand delcmdS = new SqlCommand();
delcmdS.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE id = @id";
delcmdS.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "id");
delcmdS.Connection = conn;
```

How to write correctly a SqlDataAdapter on delete, insert, update?

Comment: are you using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use cascade delete on a table Customers.

Answer (score 0):

The SqlDataAdapter is used to fill datasets based off of a select query. That is not what you seem to be looking for.

Instead, continue to use the SqlCommand object, using the **ExecuteNonQuery()** method referenced [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So, you would have code that looks like this:

```
//Bonus
SqlCommand inscmdT = new SqlCommand();
inscmdT.CommandText = "Insert into Bonus (customer_id, someAmount) values(@customer_id,     @someAmount); select id = @@IDENTITY from Bonus";
inscmdT.Connection = conn;
inscmdT.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "customer_id");
inscmdT.Parameters.Add("@someAmount", SqlDbType.Int, sizeof(Int32), "someAmount");
inscmdT.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

etc.

Comment: The parameterized query '(@name nvarchar(250),@age int)Inse' expects the parameter '@name', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

call the `SqlDataAdapter.Update(dataset)` after you change your dataset. as long as you have the proper commands set. which you have set up already just need to assign

```
SqlDataAdpater.DeleteCommand = delCMDT;
SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCOmmand = updCMT;
SQlDataAdapter.InsertCommand = incmdT
```

it would make things a lot easier if you could create a typed dataset with Visual Studio than all this is done for you. based on your database schema. also i am not sure how the poarams work with untyped datasets since I always use typed ones. which you can make yourself though very tediuos

[SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx)

Comment: The problem is to update tables. When I add new customer,  firstly must update Customers table, and then Bonus table. When I delete customers, firstly delete entry from Bonus table, and then delete entry from Customers table. If I do operations in the wrong order, I have problem with Foreign key.

Comment: @user2963950 - right you will. you will need 2 SqlDataAdapters. are you using Visual studio? and can you connect to the database with it? that will simplify this alot. anyways I would set up a wrapper class like a dataAdapterManager to handle the order of calling update and fill